# Using ng-Options how do I filter what exactly interpret the given value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I will for example for testing ,

In this example when I put filter : chart.id = 1 , and he returns me the id 1 it returns me the id 10 , how would I do that returned only id = 1 ?

http://jsfiddle.net/H6AZ2/37/

html

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<select ng-model="toAddChart" ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:chart.id='1'">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

scope

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

 $scope.chartList = [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "chart 1", "order" : 1, "active" : false },
                     { "id" : 2, "name" : "chart 2", "order" : 2, "active" : false },
                     { "id" : 3, "name" : "chart 3", "order" : 3, "active" : true },
                     { "id" : 4, "name" : "chart 4", "order" : 4, "active" : true }, 
                     { "id" : 10, "name" : "chart 10", "order" : 5, "active" : true } ];
}
```

Updated Answer Correct

that's problem in Angular version, for oldest i need using function

```
$scope.meufiltro= function(valor){
return function(obj){
    return obj.id == valor;
}
};
```

and after

```
ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:meuFiltro(1)"
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
     <select ng-model="toAddChart" 
       ng-options="chart.id as chart.name for chart in chartList | filter:{'id': 1}: true">
      <option value=""></option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6AZ2/43/) by @RaphaelMüller

Comment: @AndrewAlex change filter typo to `filter:{'id': 1}` try updated answer

Comment: @AndrewAlex try updated answer I've added strongly type check by add `:true` in filter

Comment: @AndrewAlex you should use a newer Angular version, which support the strict option for filters. or write your own filter. -> http://jsfiddle.net/H6AZ2/43/

Comment: @RaphaelMüller Thanks a lot for fiddle, I added in answer :-)

Comment: @AndrewAlex check I have added fiddle in answer which was created by Raphael

Comment: @pankajparkar actually, i just changed the angular version from 1.0.3 to 1.2.1 in the fiddle from the OP and added the strict filter ;)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller really appreciated your efforts..Thanks :)